# Nginx is using both port 80 and 8080

Tags: php, nginx, varnish

I changed listening port of nginx from 80 to 8080 in `/etc/nginx/site-enabled/default`  but when in `netstat -plnt` result it use both of them:

[image]

here is my nginx default config

```
server {
    listen 8080 default;
    root /home/mosi/workspace;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
```

}

**Problem solved**

Since I had many other config file, I just added port listening line in other configs and It work correct now
Tahnks

Comment: Also I restart and reload nginx service after this change

Comment: Are you sure you're not just running another instance or that you don't have another `server` block listening on `80`?

Comment: I have some another config file of other sites but those have not listen command

Comment: What about in your `nginx.conf` or equivalent?

Comment: I add listen line in other my configs and problem solved :|

Comment: You have a listen directive somewhere else.  Try something like `fgrep -iR listen /etc/nginx`